# SQL - Joining 3 or more tables traditional method

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm learning some SQL and I'd like to know what is the traditional way of joining 3 or more tables.

I know about using NATURAL JOINs, and JOIN ON. I'm thinking JOIN USING is possible too? But I heard that there is a traditional method of doing it, however, I can't figure it out.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT c#, fn, ln, cat
FROM TABLE1, TABLE4
WHERE (TABLE1.c# = TABLE2.c#
AND TABLE3.o# = TABLE2.o#
AND TABLE4.i = TABLE3.i);
```

But I always get the error ORA-00904: invalid identifier %s

Anybody care to help me out, or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Some advice: don't use NATURAL JOINs, except perhaps for one-off adhoc queries.

Comment: Thanks, I know. I needed this for homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example:

```
SELECT c#, fn, ln, cat
FROM TABLE1, TABLE4
WHERE (TABLE1.c# = TABLE2.c#
AND TABLE3.o# = TABLE2.o#
AND TABLE4.i = TABLE3.i);
```

... your WHERE clause references missing tables TABLE2 and TABLE3.

You would want either this:

```
SELECT c#, fn, ln, cat
FROM TABLE1, TABLE4
WHERE TABLE1.c# = TABLE4.c#;
```

OR

```
SELECT c#, fn, ln, cat
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3, TABLE4
WHERE (TABLE1.c# = TABLE2.c#
AND TABLE3.o# = TABLE2.o#
AND TABLE4.i = TABLE3.i);
```

... I am guessing you are using Oracle?  column identifiers with '#' are valid?

Comment: Yes, the second one was what I needed. I didn't add Table2 and Table3. I suppose that's why I was getting the error. I also had to modify the SELECT statement to TABLE1.C# otherwise it was an ambiguous column error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Columns with `#` are fine; Oracle uses them internally, e.g. `serial#` in the [`v$session`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10820/dynviews_3016.htm) view. Matter of taste though; I'm not personally a fan.